# How do I LINQ multi-nested lists to JSON in MVC Web Api?

Tags: json, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'd like to learn to do this, because it gives me headaches :S

**Goal:**

To make as few DB queries to get a logical JSON object for my app.

**Scenario**

An app for a school where parents can pay for activities for their children.
A parent has many students, a student has many line-items (orders), a line-item works as a join-table between student and product.

**Models:**

```
public class Parent
 {
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }

}

public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
} 


public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; } 
} 

public class LineItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int Discount {get; set;}
    // ...

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

**JSON I'd like to generate:**

```
{
    "Parent": {
        "ParentId": 10, 
        "FullName": "John Doe", 
        "Students": [
            {
                "StudentId": 12, 
                "FullName": "William Doe", 
                "ParentId": 10, 
                "LineItems": [
                    {
                        "Discount": 10, 
                        "Price": 150, 
                        "Name": "Student trip to Washington"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "Discount": 10, 
                        "Price": 20, 
                        "Name": "Halloween party"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "StudentId": 15, 
                "FullName": "Kate Mary-Jane Doe", 
                "ParentId": 10, 
                "LineItems": [
                    {
                        "Discount": 10, 
                        "Price": 110, 
                        "Name": "Spring Break to Mexico"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

I have experimented with View Models and AutoMapper, but I can't get the nested output of everything. The best I could do was get a nested Parent -> Students[] output, but could not figure out how to get to the LineItems and Products.

Comment: Did you by chance run into the circular reference problem when serializing these? Please post the automapper code you had to get the Parent -> Students[]. You should be able to do this with automapper and viewmodels, but you have to tell AutoMapper when to stop walking the graph to avoid circular references.

Answer (score 0):

Following solution may be help you

I am using Nortwnd Sample database, with 3 tables, Customers,Orders,OrdersDetails , As you know relation bewteen these tables Customer has many orders has many products

Following is working example
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
          var json = new List();

```
       foreach (var c in customers)
       {
           json.Add(new
           {
               c.CustomerID,         
               custname =c.CompanyName, 
               Orders = c.Orders.Select(o => new 
               {
                   o.OrderID,
                   o.OrderDate,
                   OrderDetails=o.Order_Details.Select(d=> new{
                  d.OrderID,
                  d.ProductID
                   })
               })
           });
       }

       var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

       var jsonString = serializer.Serialize(json);

        Response.Write(jsonString.ToString());
```

OUTPUT

```
[
    {
        "CustomerID": "WOLZA",
        "custname": "Wolski Zajazd",
        "Orders": [
            {
                "OrderID": 10374,
                "OrderDate": "/Date(849724200000)/",
                "OrderDetails": [
                    {
                        "OrderID": 10374,
                        "ProductID": 31
                    },
                    {
                        "OrderID": 10374,
                        "ProductID": 58
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "OrderID": 10611,
                "OrderDate": "/Date(869769000000)/",
                "OrderDetails": [
                    {
                        "OrderID": 10611,
                        "ProductID": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "OrderID": 10611,
                        "ProductID": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "OrderID": 10611,
                        "ProductID": 60
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "OrderID": 10792,
                "OrderDate": "/Date(882815400000)/",
                "OrderDetails": [
                    {
                        "OrderID": 10792,
                        "ProductID": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "OrderID": 10792,
                        "ProductID": 54
                    },
                    {
                        "OrderID": 10792,
                        "ProductID": 68
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "OrderID": 10870,
                "OrderDate": "/Date(886530600000)/",
                "OrderDetails": [
                    {
                        "OrderID": 10870,
                        "ProductID": 35
                    },
                    {
                        "OrderID": 10870,
                        "ProductID": 51
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "OrderID": 10906,
                "OrderDate": "/Date(888345000000)/",
                "OrderDetails": [
                    {
                        "OrderID": 10906,
                        "ProductID": 61
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "OrderID": 10998,
                "OrderDate": "/Date(891541800000)/",
                "OrderDetails": [
                    {
                        "OrderID": 10998,
                        "ProductID": 24
                    },
                    {
                        "OrderID": 10998,
                        "ProductID": 61
                    },
                    {
                        "OrderID": 10998,
                        "ProductID": 74
                    },
                    {
                        "OrderID": 10998,
                        "ProductID": 75
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "OrderID": 11044,
                "OrderDate": "/Date(893269800000)/",
                "OrderDetails": [
                    {
                        "OrderID": 11044,
                        "ProductID": 62
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```